# JavaScript- AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Hello I am trying to open a form using AJAX. On button click the form requests "http://localhost/Forms/dl_contact_dealer.html". I receive the entire document, but am having trouble appending it to the DOM.

```
function openContactDealer(){
  window.$$ = {};

  // create & setup & send xhr
  $$.xhr = getXHR();  
  var url = "http://localhost/Forms/dl_contact_dealer.html"
  ajax({
    url: url,
    ctype: "text/html",
    success: function(){
      if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        console.log(this);

        var data = this.response;

      }
    }
  });
}
```

After I receive the response, any suggestions on how to do this? I have tried using createElement, createTextNode and then appendChild.

Comment: `success` won't be called if the http request wasn't successful (i.e., HTTP 200, so you don't need to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

select an element and use element.InnerHTML to insert the response.

Comment: Do I have to do anything with the response? For instance this is not working. document.body.innerHTML(data)

Comment: if your response is a html data than just use element.InnerHTML = response